# Why is my teacher converting CNF this way?

Tags: conjunctive-normal-form

I am learning `CNF` and I have a teacher who is doing something I truly don't understand. I want to ask him later on, yet I am struggling to finish my coursework so it can't wait until then.

So..

```
 -A --> B
```

It needs to be `-A v B`. This one... this one is fine, I get it.

The thing starts when he goes further and says that it needs to be: `-A, B`... and, after that, `A,B`

And I am stunned. How does he get `-A, B` and derive `A,B` from that? And on *Wikipedia*, I can't read anything about changing `-A v B` to something else...

Can someone help me by confirming that I am right and that it should be `-A v B`... and only that?

Comment: 'Negation A, B' is not a logic statement ... nor is 'A, B' ... I don't know what your teacher is trying to do here, but it doesn't look like an inference, if you think that's what it is.

Comment: He calls it "verder kleiner maken", but I don't get why on earth that is needed. So he makes them smaller, but I am stunned to be honest. Am I correct when I say that -A v B is the ONLY good answer here?

Comment: Do you have some notes you could copy or take a picture of?

Comment: Nope, I am afraid I have not. I'll ask them and won't confuse anyone else here haha. Thanks for the reactions.

Comment: @Siyah Also check this to visualize your code: http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display

Comment: @MYGz: thanks mate, I've sent you an e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I see what is going on ...

OK, we have that:

$A \rightarrow B \Leftrightarrow \neg A \lor B$ (you can use a truth-table to verify this)

But that means:

$\neg A \rightarrow B \Leftrightarrow$

$\neg \neg A \lor B \Leftrightarrow$

$A \lor B$

Is that maybe what your instructor is trying to do?

Comment: Perhaps, yes, but how do yet get double negation A when you only have negation A --> B? I mean, where are these rules? Where can I find a good site where ALL the rules are explained?

Comment: @Siyah I was thinking that maybe he started out with $\neg A \rightarrow B$ instead of $A \rightarrow B$ so you would get an extra negation when converting to an $\lor$, and hence a double negation

Comment: Ah, got it. No, he didn't start like that, I am sure of that, but I'll just ask him. He confused me.

Comment: @Siyah  There are lots of sites ... look for 'Boolean Algebra rules' or 'logical equivalence rules'.

Comment: @Siyah You're welcome ... or should I say 'Graag gedaan!'?

Comment: Haha, I knew you were Dutch already. Thanks Bram, ik waardeer het.

Comment: @Siyah :). And just to make sure: I am sure that there is nothing 'weird' going on; you can't just drop negations unless it is a double negation of course. So, either your instructor forgot to write down a negation or you forgot to copy some negation. Anyway, don't worry that there is something you are not understanding!

Comment: That's what I though too. It will be more clear this week, merci!

Comment: @Siyah OK; let me know what you find out, just for my own interest!

Comment: you were right, he just started like that indeed.

Comment: @Siyah Good!  So nothing strange happened :) Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: I did, thanks Bram.